# Test if a binary tree satisfies the BST property

Tags: c++, tree, template, pointers

I implemented code logic provided in the EPI book to determine if a binary tree is a BST. There were two approaches, therefore I used polymorphism for the common parts. I'm also using templates. I would appreciate code review on my use of smart pointers? Anything that I should have been doing that I'm not. I did not defined any destructors, should I?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <limits>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class BinarySearchNode {

public:
    unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> leftChild;
    unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> rightChild;

    BinarySearchNode(T pData) : data(pData), leftChild(nullptr), rightChild(nullptr) {}
    BinarySearchNode(T pData, unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> pLeft, unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> pRight)
    : data(pData),leftChild(move(pLeft)), rightChild(move(pRight)) {}

    T getData() const { return data; };

private:
    T data;
};

template <typename T>
class BSTSolution {

protected:
    virtual bool isBSTValid(unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> const &node,T min, T max) = 0;

public:
    bool isBinaryTreeValidBinaryTree(unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> const &root){
        if(root == nullptr)
            return false;

        return isBSTValid(root, numeric_limits<T>::min(), numeric_limits<T>::max());
    }
};

template <typename T>
class BSTRecursiveSolution : public BSTSolution<T> {

protected:
    bool isBSTValid(unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> const &node,T min, T max) {

        if(node == nullptr)
        {
            return true;
        };

        if(node->getData() < min || node->getData() > max) {
            return false;
        }

        if(!isBSTValid(node->leftChild, min, node->getData()) || !isBSTValid(node->rightChild, node->getData(), max))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class BFSSolution : public BSTSolution<T> {

    struct QEntry {
        const unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>>& node;
        T min;
        T max;
    };

protected:
    bool isBSTValid(unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> const &node,T min, T max) {

        queue<QEntry> tempQueue;
        tempQueue.emplace(QEntry{node,min,max});
        while (!tempQueue.empty()) {
            auto const current = tempQueue.front();
            if(current.node != nullptr) {
                if(current.node->getData() < current.min || current.node->getData() > current.max) {
                    return false;
                }

                tempQueue.emplace(QEntry{current.node->leftChild,current.min,current.node->getData()});
                tempQueue.emplace(QEntry{current.node->rightChild,current.node->getData(),current.max});
            }

            tempQueue.pop();
        }
        return true;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<int>> a(new BinarySearchNode<int>(10));
    unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<int>> b(new BinarySearchNode<int>(20));

    unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<int>> root(new BinarySearchNode<int>(15, move(a),move(b)));

    root->leftChild->leftChild = std::make_unique<BinarySearchNode<int>>(8);
    root->leftChild->rightChild = std::make_unique<BinarySearchNode<int>>(13);

    root->rightChild->leftChild = std::make_unique<BinarySearchNode<int>>(18);
    root->rightChild->rightChild = std::make_unique<BinarySearchNode<int>>(21);


    cout << root->getData() << "\n";

    BSTRecursiveSolution<int> rSol;
    bool valid = rSol.isBinaryTreeValidBinaryTree(root);
    cout << "is binary tree valid? " << (valid ? "YES :) " : "NO :(") << "\n";

    BFSSolution<int> bfsSol;
    valid = bfsSol.isBinaryTreeValidBinaryTree(root);
    cout << "is binary tree valid? " << (valid ? "YES :) " : "NO :(") << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Overall the code looks fine. There's nothing wrong with your use of smart pointers as far as I can tell. I just have some small (maybe nitpicky remarks).

> I did not defined any destructors, should I?

No there's no need for them here, as the default generated destructors are fine for your scenario. The only destructor you should add is a `virtual` one for your `BSTSolution` class. But again the default generated one is just fine.

```
virtual ~BSTSolution() = default;
```

### Style

There's no need to test a `unique_ptr` against `nullptr`, since it has an `bool` overload which already does that, so you can directly use this:

```
if(!root)
    return false;
```

You should keep your notation style of (`const`) references consistent. Either put the `const` in front of the type or after it. In the first case you should put the ampersand on the type and in the second case directly after the `const`.

```
const unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>>& node
unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> const& node
```

You already used `std::make_unique` to initialize some of the child nodes in your tree. Why not also for the variables `a`, `b` and `root`? This way you can get rid of the `new` keyword altogether. Use the `auto` keyword so you don't need to write the type twice.

```
auto a = std::make_unique<BinarySearchNode<int>>(10);
auto b = std::make_unique<BinarySearchNode<int>>(20);
```

### Design

One issue with the overall design is that your `BSTSolution` class only works for arithmetic or default constructable types, since they have a template initialization for `std::numeric_limits` (and for default constructable types it might not work correctly). However your `BinarySearchNode` class happily accepts all classes as a template argument. If this code is just for yourself playing around with smart pointers that's fine but in a real environment you should either make sure your `BinarySearchNode` is only used with arithmetic (and maybe default constructable types) (e.g. using type traits), or improve your `BSTSolution` so that i can work with all classes that can be ordered using `operator<` and `operator>`. In the last case you have to find a generalized way to define infinity and -infinity for the first call of the iteration.

**Update**
One thing I forgot to mention: Whenever you are overriding a virutal method put the `override` keyword after the method. This makes it easier for humans to see that this is actually an overridden method and the compiler can check whether you are really overriding a virtual method. This is useful for catching typos and type differences.

```
 bool isBSTValid(unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> const& node, T min, T max) override
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm updating the code with the improvements you recommended. I need one clarification, for const placement, which are the first and second case. Is it the QEntry definition the second case?  I will make the class accept the infinity sentinels.

Comment: First first and second case I'm refering to putting the const in front of (1) or after (2) the type, just like the code snipped right below the sentence. So you should use one of those styles for all occurences of ``const`` references. Btw. I forget to mention one thing about the ``override`` keyword. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

**1.**

In the function

```
bool BSTRecursiveSolution<T>::isBSTValid(unique_ptr<BinarySearchNode<T>> const &node,T min, T max)
{
    if(node == nullptr)
    {
        return true;
    };

    if(node->getData() < min || node->getData() > max) {
        return false;
    }

    if(!isBSTValid(node->leftChild, min, node->getData()) || !isBSTValid(node->rightChild, node->getData(), max))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

the condition for `min` & `max` seems to allow current node's data equal to `min` or to `max`. But usually BSTs have unique keys in nodes, so I'd rather do

```
    if(node->getData() <= min || node->getData() >= max) {
        return false;
    }
```

Same applies to BFS solution.

The last part of the function can be visually simplified to

```
    return isBSTValid(node->leftChild, min, node->getData()) &&
           isBSTValid(node->rightChild, node->getData(), max);
```

**2.**

Your code would fail with determining `numeric_limits<T>::min()` and `max()` if you apply it e.g. to a tree of strings. You may solve it by delivering some kind of nullable references (say, pointers) to nearest left-side & right-side ancestors. The test would be a bit more expensive then, but the solution will gain flexibility:

```
    if(leftancestor != nullptr && node->getData() <= leftancestor->GetData()) {
        return false;
    }
    if(rightancestor != nullptr && node->getData() >= rightancestor->GetData()) {
        return false;
    }

    // the node is the closest right-side ancestor for its left child
    // and the closest left-side ancestor for its right child

    return isBSTValid(node->leftChild, leftancestor, node) &&
           isBSTValid(node->rightChild, node, rightancestor);
```

Of course the `isBSTValid` function will have to accept three pointers to nodes then, and you will call it with a root node and two `nullptr`-s (as the root has no ancestors).

Comment: Working on the template min, max issue. Some BST definitions allow duplicates.